# validate users in availability group

Tags: sql-server

I need to proactively validate database users within an AG across its nodes, by checking the users SSID and password, please help me with script.

There was an incident caused by missing SQL Account logins on a node of an Availability Group.

It might be due to the following reason User is added to the AG node but has different SID than the primary node, so user has no access to the database, • User is added to AG node with a different password than the other server has.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Select you can use on serverA to get the sid, and password if you need it.  Then use the Create Login command on serverB to have matched logins.

```
Select 'YourSqlLogin', suser_sid('YourSqlLogin'), Loginproperty('YourSqlLogin', 'PasswordHash')
```

Create Login [YourSqlLogin] 
With Password = 0x02... Hashed,   -- from above select
Sid = 0xE...,   -- from above select
Default_Database = [master],
Default_Language = [us_english], 
Check_Expiration = Off, 
Check_Policy = On